# where to start linux kernel programming?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have been programming in C for a couple of years in Linux. Now I want to work on linux kernel and contribute to kernel, if possible. I have been looking on the internet for the information about a starting point but I couldn't find one. So can any one please tell me where to begin?

Comment: Why don't you ask on their mailing lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a kernel person at all but I work with a lot of people who are very much into the kernel. They all recommend [Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672327201) as a good book on the subject. I've bought the book myself and plan to, in my copious free time, go through it.

The Kernel Mentors mailing list related resources at http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelMentors is also a good place to look at.

Comment: The entire kernelnewbies site is a good resource for starting Linux kernel programming.

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend the site [lxr.linux.no](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees) as a browsable source code repository.
It contains version 0.0.1 an up. With the help of this site, it is very easy to search for keywords in the kernel source on different versions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically venturing into kernel programming starts off with a need to fiddle with services provided by the kernel....Me for example ..i had a need to fiddle with the IP packets generated and arriving on the kernel network stack....so started of writing LKMs,.,,kernel modules.And understand becomes easier if you have good understand of general Operating System Concepts.For example there was this book which i referred during my engineering undergraduation days...Operating System Concepts Author Silberschatz Galvin..even though i never cracked my head understanding user space and kernel space..that book did look into core concept at a more naive level...and it looked in from general OS point of view not specific to linux as such..now that i am more into kernel space programming that i realize how beautifully that book ventured into both user space and kernel space concepts....it just starts off with NEED to get into kernel side...from  user space